# Rate Expression with two products

Tags: kinetics, stoichiometry

**Consider the two following cases**

***Case 1: Two Same Products***

Given the following chemical reaction,

$$A + B \rightarrow C + C$$

where C are radicals, therefore I am not writing $2C$ on the right hand side.

If we are to write the rate equation for the above expression, which one of the following will be correct.

$$\frac{d[C]}{dt} = k \cdot [A][B]$$

or will it be

$$\frac{d[C]}{dt} = 2\cdot k \cdot [A][B]$$

Do we write the 2 given that there are two of the products on the right hand side?

***Case 2: Two Same Reactants***

Now considering the following,

$$2A + B \rightarrow C$$

Are the following correct?

$$\frac{d[A]}{dt} = -2k \cdot [A][B]$$

$$\frac{d[B]}{dt} = k \cdot [A][B]$$

$$\frac{d[C]}{dt} = 2k \cdot [A][B]$$

Do we multiply with the stoichiometric coefficient for each reactant? So if there were 2A and 2B then would we write $4[A][B]$? I find this part of kinetics to be a bit confusing, and it would be great to get some clarity on it.

Comment: The general relationship  is given in this answer https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/reaction-rate-coefficient-constant-multiplier-for-equation-with-multiple-atoms-c/103078#103078

Comment: @porphyrin Thank you for the link. It also helped out a lot.

Comment: In case 2, shouldn't $[A]$ be squared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***Case 2: Two Same Reactants***
> $$2A + B \rightarrow C$$
> Are the following correct?
> $$\frac{d[A]}{dt} = -2k \cdot [A][B]$$
> $$\frac{d[B]}{dt} = -k \cdot [A][B]$$
> $$\frac{d[C]}{dt} = 2k \cdot [A][B]$$

Let's call $k \cdot [A][B]$ the rate. Your equations simplify to:
$$\frac{d[A]}{dt} = -2 \cdot \mathrm{rate}$$
$$\frac{d[B]}{dt} = - \mathrm{rate}$$
$$\frac{d[C]}{dt} = 2 \cdot \mathrm{rate}$$

The first two equations are correct. They are consistent with the stoichiometry and they happen to be definitions of the rate. The last one is incorrect. If a certain amount of B reacts, the same amount of C is formed.

> Do we multiply with the stoichiometric coefficient for each reactant? So if there were 2A and 2B then would we write $4[A][B]$?

No, just for the reactant whose concentration change you are considering on the left hand side.

> ***Case 1: Two Same Products***
> $$A + B \rightarrow C + C$$
> If we are to write the rate equation for the above expression, which one of the following will be correct.
> $$\frac{d[C]}{dt} = k \cdot [A][B]$$
> or will it be
> $$\frac{d[C]}{dt} = 2\cdot k \cdot [A][B]$$

The lower expression is correct if the two Cs in the chemical equation refer to the same species. If not, they should have different names, like C1 and C2 or something. Your example reaction equation is kind of unusual, but something similar occurs when you have multiple steps in a reaction making the same species:

$$\ce{A + B -> C + D}$$
$$\ce{D + E -> C}$$

The net reaction would be (if there is sufficient E to use up all of D)
$$\ce{A + B + E -> 2C}$$

and you are not be able to distinguish species C made from the first or the second reaction step if everything happens in one phase ("one pot reaction").

Comment: @Karsten Theis**Case 2: Two Same Reactants**
$$\text{Is the following expression correct?}$$
$$\text{rate}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d[A]}{dt} =\frac{d[B]}{dt} =\frac{d[C]}{dt}=-k \cdot [A][B]$$

Comment: @AdnanAL-Amleh Almost: rates are defined as positive, and when C is made, A and B are used up (decrease in concentration). So the correct expressions are:
$$\mathrm{rate} = -\frac{d[\ce{A}]}{2 dt} = -\frac{d[\ce{B}]}{dt} = \frac{d[\ce{C}]}{dt} = k \cdot [\ce{A}]^m [\ce{B}]^n$$ I added the exponents in the rate law to show that we don't now the order of reaction and would have to measure it.

Comment: Thanks If we call $k \cdot [A]^m[B]^n$ the rate. Can we simplify the following expression(second expression in ***case 2*** in the above answer   )$$\frac{d[B]}{dt} = -k \cdot [A]^m[B]^n$$
 to:
$$\frac{d[B]}{dt} = -k \cdot \mathrm{rate}$$ or
$$\frac{d[B]}{dt} = \mathrm{rate}$$